# Tcp latency analysis in wireshark

Tags: tcp, firewall, wireshark, latency

I wanted to know what all factors do I need to check while analysing latency issue on the firewall Wireshark's capture.?

I know about timestamps (before previous packet reached).. But nothing after than that

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about latency of HTTP transaction, you can consider 3 aspects:

- roundtrip time, typically it's the time from your HTTP request to the TCP ACK for the request
- Initial response time: that's the time between your HTTP request and first packet in the HTTP response.
- Total response time:  that's the time between your HTTP request and last packet of HTTP response (Wireshark will tell you the last packet of response since that's when you see the full http response)

Good luck.